# FacebookConnect Api in Codename one

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, codenameone, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on FacebookConnect Api and I am successfully fetching user data like picture, email, name, etc. but I have to fetch Facebook feed and display in the list, So how can I do it in Codename one.

Answer (score 0):

The Codename One API only provides the login portion for Facebook. In the past we had a `FacebookAccess` class but decided to deprecate it as it was a constant struggle to keep up with their changing/compatibility breaking API.

The solution is to use graph queries directly, this is demonstrated in the [chat tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-3.html) albeit with a relatively simple use case.

Comment: I know that but how can i change Image dynamically when program get user Facebook profile picture from Facebook at run time

Comment: This is the Image declaration of my code                                                   **user = theme.getImage("user.png");
userLabel = new Label(user);**                                                                                 and i want to change my image dynamically when profile picture data received from facebook

Comment: The chat tutorial demonstrates fetching the image dynamically from facebook or google